# Is there a way to change a value in all documents on firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm a beginner creating an mobile app with react-native and firebase.
I have a value stored in many documents and i want to update the value in all the documents

i tried with .where() clause but i got an error

```
firebase.firestore().collection('myCollection').where('myValue','==','oldValue').update({myValue:newValue});
```

I expected the data changed but i got this warning:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _reactNativeFirebase.default.firestore(...).collection(...).where(...).update is not a function
```

Please excuse my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't provide a way to update documents in bulk based on their current values.  There is no SQL-like "update where" type of syntax. You'll have to first query and read all the documents you want to change, then update them with their new values.

Comment: so if i want to update all the documents. i should get their id first then update them one by one

Comment: Yes, you need to do that.